# Why my script returns a segmentation error when executing a command via ssh?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that is supposed to run applications with arguments on a remote computer. On the computer, root just needs to write the command:

```
# ./MyApp -t '{"name":"john"}'
```

So on my own computer I wrote a script (it is simplified in terms of what is actually to show the problem):

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="{\"name\":\"john\"}"
echo "VAR: $VAR"
COMMAND="./MyAPP -t '$VAR'"
echo "COMMAND: $COMMAND"
ssh root@192.168.100.1 "$COMMAND"
```

Output:

```
$ ./my_script 
VAR: {"name":"john"}
COMMAND: ./MyApp -t '{"name":"john"}'
root@192.168.100.1's password: 
Segmentation fault
```

Why does I get segmentation error?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to enclose `$COMMAND` in quotes in the line `ssh root@192.168.100.1 "$COMMAND"` ? Because it becomes `ssh root@192.168.100.1 "./MyApp -t '{"name":"john"}'"` and the argument becomes `"./MyApp -t '{"`

Comment: Because `./MyAPP` segfaults?

Comment: I changed to **ssh root@192.168.100.1 $COMMAND** but it didn't help

Comment: What happens if you don't pass a command, but open an interactive ssh with `ssh root@192.168.100.1`?

Comment: @user1934428 it will ask for a password and then connect me to root

Comment: So you have learned that it is not your ssh which crashes. The next step is to test your command interactively on the remote host.

Comment: I feel obligated to point out what a horrible idea it is to have your machine configured to allow root login over ssh.  That should be blocked in your sshd configuration.  Instead, login as a normal user with `sudo` privileges for that one command.